# Change TARGET compile name for QT application

Tags: c++, qt

In my QT-Creator project, in .pro file I set my exe name like this

```
TARGET=Dashboard
```

However in the same .pro file I define

```
DEFINES += DEMO_VERSION
```

I uncomment this line in order to compile a DEMO version of the application. What i want to know is, how can i change the TARGET name of my application to contain the name Demo when the DEMO version is being compiled?

```
TARGET=Dashboard_Demo
```

Pseudo code

```
#ifndef DEMO_VERSION
    TARGET=Dashboard_Demo
#else
    TARGET=Dashboard
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation for `qmake` [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html), adding the following to your *.pro* file should work:

```
CONFIG += DEMO

...


DEMO {
    DEFINES += DEMO_VERSION
    TARGET=Dashboard
} else {
    TARGET=Dashboard_Demo
}
```

I added the value `DEMO` to the `CONFIG` variable, and then used it to define both your `DEFINES` and the `TARGET`.

Comment: in your .pro :P